# Do threads share time slot alloted to process

Tags: multithreading

Do threads belonging to the same process share the time alloted to the process or the time alloted to the process depends on the number of threads in the process....i.e a time slot is alloted to each thread by CPU...???

Comment: Link below will answer your question (For Linux OS):
In one sentence, each thread gets its own time slice. For full answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601155/does-linux-schedule-a-process-or-a-thread

Answer (score 0):

A general answer doesn't exist since it depends on the policy adopted by any specific OS.

Three common choices are:

- 1 to 1, every thread has it's own schedulable entity
- N to 1, all threads of the same process aren't seen by the OS kernel, so just the whole process is scheduled (bad for multi-threading but good for legacy, they are somewhat similar to green threads)
- N to M, N threads are mapped to M schedulable entities (this is an hybrid approach that tries to be a compromise but it raises complexity of the scheduling)

More detailed explaination [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#Models).

Comment: HOW the time is allocated doesn't depend on how the threads are managed with respect to processes but by the scheduling policy adopted by the OS. eg: if it's round-robin and 1 to 1 then every thread receives the same quantum of time, if instead it's N to 1 then all the threads of the same process receive just one quantum and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there's good documentation about how threads are selected to run [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685096%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Thread priority is a combination of per-process and per-thread information.

Comment: This is a very good question, can any body answer how it happens in linux, becuase i read linux does not differentiate between thread and process